# Why joining two spark dataframes fail unless I add ".as('alias)" to both?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Assume there are 2 Spark DataFrames we'd like to join, for whatever reason:

```
val df1 = Seq(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)).toDF("agent", "in_count")
val df2 = Seq(("A", 2), ("C", 2), ("D", 2)).toDF("agent", "out_count")
```

It can be done with the code like this:

```
val joinedDf = df1.as('d1).join(df2.as('d2), ($"d1.agent" === $"d2.agent"))

// Result:
val joinedDf.show

+-----+--------+-----+---------+
|agent|in_count|agent|out_count|
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
|    A|       1|    A|        2|
|    C|       3|    C|        2|
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
```

Now, what I don't understand, why does it work only as long as I use aliases `df1.as(d1)` and `df2.as(d2)`? I can imagine that there would be name clashes between the columns if I wrote it bluntly like

```
val joinedDf = df1.join(df2, ($"df1.agent" === $"df2.agent")) // fails
```

But...I don't understand why can't I use `.as(alias)` *with only one DF of the two*:

```
df1.as('d1).join(df2, ($"d1.agent" === $"df2.agent")).show()
```

fails with

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`df2.agent`' given input columns: [agent, in_count, agent, out_count];;
'Join Inner, (agent#25 = 'df2.agent)
:- SubqueryAlias d1
:  +- Project [_1#22 AS agent#25, _2#23 AS in_count#26]
:     +- LocalRelation [_1#22, _2#23]
+- Project [_1#32 AS agent#35, _2#33 AS out_count#36]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#32, _2#33]
```

Why is the last example invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello When you use alias `DataFrame` is converted into `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [agent: string, in_count: int]` so you can use `$"d1.agent"` over there.

If you want to join on the DataFrame, you can do like this:

```
scala> val joinedDf = df1.join(df2, (df1("agent") === df2("agent")))
joinedDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [agent: string, in_count: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> joinedDf.show
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
|agent|in_count|agent|out_count|
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
|    A|       1|    A|        2|
|    C|       3|    C|        2|
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Ah, indeed! It seems didn't pay enough attention to the actual types on each step of data transform. Thanks a lot for pointing this out!